# setup grails spring security on single instance elastic beanstalk

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, spring-security, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have successfully got my app to work with the load balancer.  As a cost-cutting measure I'm moving my app to a single instance on Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I was able to create an .ebextensions file with a singlessl.config and properly get my SSL cert to work in the WAR file by manually going to `https://www.example.com/login`

So I know my war file/ssl do work on a single instance.

What I have not been able to get to work is getting spring security to work.

No matter what variation of configuration I try the browser always dies with 'error too many redirects'.  This happens when I type in just the home page for the app without https (http://example.com)

I think the redirects are going from http to https and back, or something in the app/apache/tomcat going back between different ports.

There is something amiss between spring security, apache, and/or tomcat, but I'm not sure what.

At this point if the entire website is secure I would take that instead of having secure/non-secure pages.

My grails spring security config (the last variation I tried, there were about 10 I've attempted) is:

```
grails.serverURL = "https://www.example.com"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort = 80
grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort = 443
grails.plugins.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
        '/**': 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL'
```

Is there something I have to do in Tomcat or Apache to get this to work in Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: I know you have only 1 instance, but is your instance behind an ELB? I had tricky situations with HTTP redirection if the load balancer has the SSL termination, all the calls reaches the webserver on HTTP and this cause a redirection loop. ( I had to check the X_Forwarded_Proto header instead of the incoming port.)

Comment: I'm trying to remove the load balancer so I don't have to pay 2x the charges.  Everything works fine with a load balancer.  It all falls apart when I go to a single instance.  X_Forwarded_Proto isn't applicable in a single instance.

Comment: You obviously has a redirection in the Grails layer. Do you have anything on tomcat/beanstalk level? Can you confirm that you don't have any ELB front of the single instance?

Comment: The application face-planted after I removed ELB, so I know I removed it successfully.  I had to create an .ebextensions file at that point to get the SSL working in the single instance.  I was able to go to https://example.com directly.  What I could not do was go to http://example.com and have it redirect to https://example.com.  That's when the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in the browser occurred.  I haven't touched the tomcat/apache default configuration that comes with EBS on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/channelSecurity.html) for spring security channel security configuration. Also you may need to provide :

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderName = 'X-Forwarded-Proto'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderValue = 'http'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderName = 'X-Forwarded-Proto'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderValue = 'https'
```

In .ebextensions, you can place server.xml for in which:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
<!-- Add this line --> 
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" protocolHeader="X-Forwarded-Proto" internalProxies="10\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|192\.168\.\d+\.\d+|169\.254\.\d+\.\d+|127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|172\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\.\d+\.\d+" />

  </Host>
```

to be applied to server container like tomcat. I do not have much knowledge about internalProxies.